# UnsatisfiedConditionException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, lambda

I have this code which it needs to throw and exception inside a Lambda:

```java
public static <T, E extends Exception> Consumer<T> consumerWrapper(
      Consumer<T> consumer,
      Class<E> clazz) {
    return i -> {
      try {
        consumer.accept(i);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        try {
          E exCast = clazz.cast(ex);
          System.err.println(
              "Exception occured : " + exCast.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassCastException ccEx) {
          throw ex;
        }
      }
    };
}
```

```java
public static void processConditions(@NotNull List<EntityCondition> conditions)
      throws UnsatisfiedConditionException {
    conditions.forEach(
       consumerWrapper(
           entityCondition -> {
              throw new UnsatisfiedConditionException(entityCondition);
           }, UnsatisfiedConditionException.class));
}
```

Even with this approach, compiling this would throw an error:
`UnsatisfiedConditionException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`

What could be wrong or missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote out the lambda as an anonymous class instead

```
new Consumer<EntityCondition>() {
  @Override public void accept(EntityCondition entityCondition) {
    throw new UnsatisfiedConditionException(entityCondition);
  }
}
```

...then it would make complete sense that it doesn't compile: the method `accept` in `Consumer` is not defined to throw an exception.  It would have to be `public void accept(..) throws UnsatisfiedConditionException { ... }` or the like.

So what you need *can't be Consumer*.  You have to make your own functional interface.

```
interface ThrowingConsumer<T> {
  void accept(T t) throws Exception;
}
```

... and then convert it to a `Consumer`:

```
public static <T, E extends Exception> Consumer<T> consumerWrapper(
  ThrowingConsumer<T> consumer,
  Class<E> clazz) { ... }
```

...except that you can't `throw ex`, because that would break it again.  You will have to decide what the appropriate behavior when you can't throw that exception is.

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas have to be treated like anonymous classes.

Let's say that there is an interface called `AbstractClass`.

```
public interface AbstractClass {
    void requestWork();
}
```

Creating an implementation of it would look like this:

```
public static AbstractClass getImplementation() {
    return new AbstractClass() {
        @Override
        public void requestWork() {
            throw new Exception(); // <- javac: "Unhandled exception: java.lang.Exception"
        }
    };
}
```

The lambda-eqivalent would look like this:

```
public static AbstractClass getImplementation() {
    return () -> {
        throw new Exception();
    };
}
```

The compiler can't add a `throws`-declaration to the overriden method since the method is declared in the abstract class.

How to fix this? You have three options:

1. Add a throws declaration in the class that is implemented by the lambda
2. Use `try`-`catch` statements to handle the problem in the lambda
3. Use a subclass of `RuntimeException` since the Java compiler won't force you to handle those.

You can also catch the exception and rethrow it as a `RuntimeException` like this:

```
try {
    throw new Exception();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: There's a rather very obvious fourth option you're missing: Just.... use.... a for(:).

Comment: Yes. But he wants to know why the compiler complains and how to fix this kind of problem, not what would be the best option in this case. The questions of StackOverflow often contain code that is just made to show the problem, not to actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using your shiny fancy new hammer to smear butter on your toast. It works, sure, but not very well. Calling `forEach` on a Collection instance is not a good idea unless you already have the lambda from someplace else. `list.forEach(x -> { .. })` is bad code style. Jst use `for( var x: list) {}` instead. These forms are just as short, there is no performance benefit whatsoever to a blind forEach, and the forEach has a ton of downsides that the `for` does not: The lambda is not (mutable) local variable transparent, not control flow transparent, and not checked exception transparent. All serious issues, as you're noticing.

forEach on streams is fine as a final terminal operation after a bunch of `map`, `filter,` `flatMap`, etc operations. It's not a global 'stop using foreach forever! kind of thing'.

### Yeah yeah. Answer my question

Well, hey, your funeral.

Lambdas are not valid in java unless in a context that makes clear which FunctionalInterface they are filling in for. In this case, it's the first arg to `consumerWrapper` (which does nothing useful, I'll get to this in a second), and that takes a `Consumer<T>`. Let's look at the definition of Consumer:

```
package java.util.function;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Consumer<T> {
    void accept(T t);
}
```

Therefore, your lambda is interpreted as an impl of that `accept` method. Notably, that means it can't throw anything (except RuntimeExceptions and Errors, as everything is allowed to throw these).

Hence, this is just not going to work. As long as you insist on using `Consumer<T>` as an **input** you're dead in the water.

Try this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingConsumer<T, E extends Throwable> {
    void accept(T t) throws E;

    public static Consumer<T> withRethrownExceptions(ThrowingConsumer<T> in) {
        return t -> {
            try {
                in.accept(t);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) { throw e; }
            } catch (Error e) { throw e; }
            } catch (Throwable t) throw new RuntimeException("Uncaught", t); }
        };
}
```